# SQL Stored Procedure With One To Many Relationship Return Only Most Recent Record

Tags: sql

I've been having a terrible time with this. I created a stored procedure to return a corresponding record, but one of the tables has multiple print jobs so it returns multiple records. I only want the most recent requested print job to return and I can't get it to work correctly.

Please help!

```
SELECT  PrintJobs.WORDERKey,
        PrintJobs.JobNumber, 
        WORDER.U_DateRequired AS DateRequired,
        ProductMaster.PartFileItemID, 
        WORDER.ManufacturingDepartment AS MfgDept,
        PrintJobs.Copies AS LabelCopies,
        PrintJobs.ExpiryDate AS JobExpiryDate,
        PrintJobs.Batch,
        PrintJobs.JulianDate AS JobJulianDate,
        ProductMaster.Description, 
        ProductMaster.PackFormat, 
        ProductMaster.IngDec, 
        ProductMaster.BarCodeNumber, 
        ProductMaster.CustomerProductCode, 
        ProductMaster.CriticalInstruction, 
        ProductMaster.StorageInstruction, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCaseTitle, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode1, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode2, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode3, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode4, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription1, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription2, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription3, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription4, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec1, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec2, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec3, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec4, 
        ProductMaster.CookingInstruction, 
        ProductMaster.LogoFilename,
        ProductMaster.ProductExpiryRule,
        ExpiryRulesMaster.GS1_AppID,
        ProductMaster.LabelTemplateID, 
        CASE WHEN ProductMaster.PartFileItemID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS LabelDefExists,
        LabelTemplateMaster.FileName, 
        CASE WHEN [DateFormat] = 'Default' THEN ExpiryRulesMaster.DateFormatString ELSE [DateFormat] END AS DateFormatString, 
        ExpiryRulesMaster.DateRounding, 
        ExpiryRulesMaster.ExcludeXmasNewYear,
        PART.ExternalShelfLifeTotalDays,
        CustomOptions.Tagline,
        CustomOptions.ShortName AS CustShortName,
        ExpiryRulesMaster.LabelText AS ExpiryRuleLabelText, 
        ProductMaster.inner_hDescription, 
        ProductMaster.inner_vDescription, 
        ProductMaster.inner_CustCode, 
        ProductMaster.inner_Storage, 
        ProductMaster.inner_WarningMsg, 
        ProductMaster.inner_Dateformat, 
        ProductMaster.inner_SpecialCode, 
        ProductMaster.LabelType,
        ProductMaster.inner_MicroSuiteCode, 
        ProductMaster.inner_PackWeight, 
        ProductMaster.inner_JDateFormat,
        ProductMaster.CustomOptionID, 
        ProductMaster.inner_PrintLogo,
        PART.NominalWeight,
        ProductMaster.IngDec_html, 
        ProductMaster.IngDec_Active, 
        PrintJobs.PrintJobsID,
        MaxJobs.MaxJob,
        PrintJobs.DateEntered

FROM        ProductMaster RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Partfileitemid,
                --JobNumber, 
                MAX(dateentered) MaxJob 
            FROM PrintJobs 
            GROUP BY PartFileItemID
        )
        MaxJobs ON ProductMaster.PartFileItemID = MaxJobs.PartFileItemID RIGHT OUTER       JOIN 
        PrintJobs ON PrintJobs.PartFileItemID = MaxJobs.PartFileItemID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        LabelTemplateMaster ON ProductMaster.LabelTemplateID = LabelTemplateMaster.LabelTemplateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CustomOptions ON ProductMaster.CustomOptionID = CustomOptions.CustomOptionID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ExpiryRulesMaster ON ProductMaster.ProductExpiryRule = ExpiryRulesMaster.ExpiryRule LEFT OUTER JOIN
        [F8Extract].[dbo].[WORDER] ON PrintJobs.WORDERKey = WORDER.WORDERKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
        [F8Extract].[dbo].[PART] ON ProductMaster.PartFileItemID = Part.PartFileItemID                  

WHERE       PrintJobs.WORDERKey = @WORDERKey



END
```

Thanks,

Stacy

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to look at `TOP` and `ORDER BY`, i.e.

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        PrintJobs.WORDERKey,
        PrintJobs.JobNumber, 
        WORDER.U_DateRequired AS DateRequired,
        ProductMaster.PartFileItemID, 
        WORDER.ManufacturingDepartment AS MfgDept,
        PrintJobs.Copies AS LabelCopies,
        PrintJobs.ExpiryDate AS JobExpiryDate,
        PrintJobs.Batch,
        PrintJobs.JulianDate AS JobJulianDate,
        ProductMaster.Description, 
        ProductMaster.PackFormat, 
        ProductMaster.IngDec, 
        ProductMaster.BarCodeNumber, 
        ProductMaster.CustomerProductCode, 
        ProductMaster.CriticalInstruction, 
        ProductMaster.StorageInstruction, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCaseTitle, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode1, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode2, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode3, 
        ProductMaster.MixedCode4, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription1, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription2, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription3, 
        ProductMaster.MixedDescription4, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec1, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec2, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec3, 
        ProductMaster.MixedIngDec4, 
        ProductMaster.CookingInstruction, 
        ProductMaster.LogoFilename,
        ProductMaster.ProductExpiryRule,
        ExpiryRulesMaster.GS1_AppID,
        ProductMaster.LabelTemplateID, 
        CASE WHEN ProductMaster.PartFileItemID IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS LabelDefExists,
        LabelTemplateMaster.FileName, 
        CASE WHEN [DateFormat] = 'Default' THEN ExpiryRulesMaster.DateFormatString ELSE [DateFormat] END AS DateFormatString, 
        ExpiryRulesMaster.DateRounding, 
        ExpiryRulesMaster.ExcludeXmasNewYear,
        PART.ExternalShelfLifeTotalDays,
        CustomOptions.Tagline,
        CustomOptions.ShortName AS CustShortName,
        ExpiryRulesMaster.LabelText AS ExpiryRuleLabelText, 
        ProductMaster.inner_hDescription, 
        ProductMaster.inner_vDescription, 
        ProductMaster.inner_CustCode, 
        ProductMaster.inner_Storage, 
        ProductMaster.inner_WarningMsg, 
        ProductMaster.inner_Dateformat, 
        ProductMaster.inner_SpecialCode, 
        ProductMaster.LabelType,
        ProductMaster.inner_MicroSuiteCode, 
        ProductMaster.inner_PackWeight, 
        ProductMaster.inner_JDateFormat,
        ProductMaster.CustomOptionID, 
        ProductMaster.inner_PrintLogo,
        PART.NominalWeight,
        ProductMaster.IngDec_html, 
        ProductMaster.IngDec_Active, 
        PrintJobs.PrintJobsID,
        MaxJobs.MaxJob,
        PrintJobs.DateEntered

FROM        ProductMaster RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Partfileitemid,
                --JobNumber, 
                MAX(dateentered) MaxJob 
            FROM PrintJobs 
            GROUP BY PartFileItemID
        )
        MaxJobs ON ProductMaster.PartFileItemID = MaxJobs.PartFileItemID RIGHT OUTER       JOIN 
        PrintJobs ON PrintJobs.PartFileItemID = MaxJobs.PartFileItemID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        LabelTemplateMaster ON ProductMaster.LabelTemplateID = LabelTemplateMaster.LabelTemplateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        CustomOptions ON ProductMaster.CustomOptionID = CustomOptions.CustomOptionID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ExpiryRulesMaster ON ProductMaster.ProductExpiryRule = ExpiryRulesMaster.ExpiryRule LEFT OUTER JOIN
        [F8Extract].[dbo].[WORDER] ON PrintJobs.WORDERKey = WORDER.WORDERKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
        [F8Extract].[dbo].[PART] ON ProductMaster.PartFileItemID = Part.PartFileItemID                  

WHERE       PrintJobs.WORDERKey = @WORDERKey
ORDER BY PrintJobs.Number DESC
```

Note change the `PrintJobs.Number` to whatever field specifies the time order.